# Textinput field disables radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but I'd like to find the simplest way, preferably CSS-based.

I have a simple form with four radio buttons followed by a text field.  I need to disable the radio buttons if the user clicks in the text field.  This is my basic code, and granted, I'm still learning about forms, so there may be other errors:

```
<div class="left-column">
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="location" value="address-1" id="address-1" checked="checked" />
<label for="address-1">First location</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="location" value="address-2" id="address-2" />
<label for="address-2">Second location</label>
</div>

<div class="right-column">
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="location" value="address-3" id="address-3" />
<label for="address-3">Third location</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="location" value="address-4" id="address-4" />
<label for="address-4">Fourth location</label>
</div>

<div>
<textarea id="location" type="text" tabindex="1" name="location" cols="22" rows="1">    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use JS for this not CSS.

Comment: You cannot disable form elements with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you can do something like this (which disables the radio buttons with class `radio` when the user clicks into the text field):

```
$("#location").click(function(){
    $(".radio").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Now if you need to enable the radio buttons if the user clicks outside (or in another way leaves the text field) the text field, you could just change `click` in the code above to `blur`, like this:

```
$("#location").blur(function(){
    $(".radio").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: I've tried these, and I note that when the script is in place, the default ticked button does not untick, nor do others if they are ticked, when the user put his cursor in the textinput field.  So I'm not sure if the javascript actually works.  I should also ask whether the "blur" version is meant to substitute the "click" version or if you meant it in addition to.

Comment: The `blur` version I added if you wanted to make it possible to reset the radio buttons to default setting (enabled) again if the user clicks outside the text field. Take a look at this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/38k3z/), to see what I mean.

Comment: The reason your script doesn't work might be that I also have a js watermark script running on that field.  Perhaps the two don't like each other: `code` jQuery(function($){
 $("#location").Watermark(" Other location");
});

Comment: Hmm... perhaps it will work if you change `click(function(){` to `focus(function(){`?

Comment: Yes, and unfortunately that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, the following would work:

```
window.onload = function()
{
   document.getElementById('location').addEventListener('click', function()
   {
      for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
      {
      document.getElementsByClassName('radio')[i].disabled = true;
      }
   });
}
```

Because your ***[radio buttons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button)*** are in a class, and there are four of them.

To re-enable all of them, set `disabled` to false:

```
document.getElementById('location').addEventListener('click', function()
       {
          for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
          {
          document.getElementsByClassName('radio')[i].disabled = false;
          }
       });
```

CSS is not cable of this, though, because it is only a [Style Sheet Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

Comment: Now, this works very well!  What more can be done, though, to reset the state in case someone changes his mind in the text field and wants to click a radio button instead?

Comment: Set disabled = false; look at edit.  Put that code on your radio buttons' click events to re-enable them: `for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
      {
      document.getElementsByClassName('radio')[i].addEventListener('click', function() { for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) { document.getElementsByClassName('radio').disabled = false; } }
      }`  Also, please mark my answer as **'correct.'**

Comment: @DanielLisik That's why nobody uses IE8 and definitely not below.

Comment: @ManofSnow About 8.7 % of the Internet users is a notable amount, in my opinion. http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201211-201311

Comment: To achieve the reset state, it's not quite clear whether this added code is added to the first code, or where it goes altogether.  I tried changing true to false on the initial code, but then the effect is lost.

Comment: @user604488  Add this to the first code, then: `for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) { document.getElementsByClassName('radio')[i].addEventListener('click', function() { for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) { document.getElementsByClassName('radio').disabled = false; } } }` It will enable the radio buttons if you click them.

Comment: Sorry, but without a crash course in javascript, I'm just mangling your work when I try to apply it.  It's probably because I can't find the right braces (or no braces) to fuse these pieces together.  The result is that nothing is working.

Comment: I'd be delighted to mark this as the best answer if only I can find a solution to my last query.

Comment: @user604488 I'm sorry, but you need *some* programming knowledge, and you don't have any problems, so I cannot help you, but to tell you to make a cancel button that the user can click to un-disable them.  That's your answer, and I *did* answer your 'question', so technically this *should* be marked as a correct answer.

Comment: No help to me at all.